# Save list in Python

Tags: image, list, python-2.7, arraylist

I want to save a list of strings in the python Array.
My code is as below:

```
import os
Images_list=[os.listdir("/home/metal-machine/Pictures/new")]
print Images_list[0]
```

It only prints the list in the [0] and when I use

```
print Images_list[1]
```

It returns the error as:
    IndexError: list index out of range

I am sure this "index out of range" is because all the elements of list are not separated by comma.

For that I can also use split() method in Python.

```
images_list.split()
```

And the above command splits the files but putting commas in-between all of them, but why Python By-default not put commas in between all the elements? Is sunch kind of list is valid in Python?

Comment: I also tried print ', '.join(mylist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write code that is a bit more error free

```
for images in Images_list:
    print images
```